# How to fix the nullpointerexception that comes up in Eclipse when trying to open an Android XML file?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Since I updated the ADT plugin to v1.21 in Eclipse, I can no longer easily open any XML layout files in my Android project. As soon as, I click on the file, It throws NullPointerException. Here are the stack traces from the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonMatchingStrategy.matches(CommonMatchingStrategy.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.checkEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.findEditors(WorkbenchPage.java:2223)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.findEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.isOpenInEditor(EditorUtility.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart.linkToEditor(PackageExplorerPart.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart.access$2(PackageExplorerPart.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.linkToEditor(PackageExplorerPart.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.selectionChanged(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I can open the file if I right-click on it, and tell it t open with the Legacy Android Layout editor, but it's obviously not good solution. I tried going into Eclipse preferences, and made sure that the file associations for the XML files are set correctly.

Comment: Looks like an entirely Eclipse bug.  I reckon you'll have to log it with them.  Maybe it's common and already being discussed on their fora?

Comment: there were a few threads from previous versions doing something similar, but none of the solutions seem to apply

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Android Developer Tools.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by closing all open project files in the editor and restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Worked for me. Close Project, Close All open files, Restart Eclipse, Open project

Comment: Didn't work for me. Also when closed all project and restarted - the first one was automatically reopened... tried a few times - close and restart, and it reproduces.

Answer (score 0):

I switch to a new workspace, then everything works fine.